# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: asp.net, scripting, javascript

Something wrong with this line of code:

```
changeimage('image1', 'Photos/Customers/Test1/Dock.jpg')
```

What is wrong?

Edit:
Javascript:

```
function changeImage(image_name, image_src) {
    document[image_name].src = image_src; 
}
```

Debug

```
 <img id="ctl00_Main_gridThumbnails_ctl06_tb1" src="Photos/Customers/Test1/Forest-tn.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$Main$gridThumbnails$ctl06$photolink" id="ctl00_Main_gridThumbnails_ctl06_photolink" value="~/Photos/Customers/Test1/Forest.jpg" />
```

Comment: Give us some more context. I would say that `changeimage` is probably not defined.

Comment: The `changeimage` function is not found.

Comment: All the javascripts are found, so it's not that

Answer (score 1):

If your code is exactly as you have shown us, then it seems the problem lies in capitalization. You have defined `changeImage` with a capital 'I', but you called `changeimage` with a lower-case 'i'.

Try changing to:

```
changeImage('image1', 'Photos/Customers/Test1/Dock.jpg');
```

If your Javascript is in a different file, it's also possible that your link to that file is broken and is not getting loaded.

Comment: Hold on, yeah none of my javascripts are being used/not working - I have masterpage with:

    <script src="/JS/Scripts/changeimage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Use Firebug to see whether you're getting a 404 on that script.

Comment: All the javascripts are found, so it's not that

Comment: Is it the capital 'I' problem? What do you get if you type this into your browser's location bar on your page? `javascript:alert(changeimage);`

Answer (score 1):

FirstSimilar to me, in my JScript code, I only wrongly spell the ID 'Name' to 'Nama' make the debugger unable to find the Object I have declared and it gives me this error !!

Eg code:

```
DDLNameSample_Delete.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:return validateDropDown_NameSample('" + DDLNamaSample_Delete.ClientID + "');")

btnDelete_NameSample.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return validateDropDown_NameSample('" + DDLNameSample_Delete.ClientID + "');")
```

If you you can see on the First line, I have wrongly spell `DDLNamaSample_Delete` instead of `DDLNameSample_Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

"Object expected" simply means that the code expected to find something (an object) but didn't find it.

With just that single line, it's hard to diagnose the problem.  If the code is looking for some object, you have to track down where the object *should have been* created.  In your case, make sure the function is defined somewhere before you try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error too. And seems like this error is caused due to:

1. The name of the object is different than being used.
2. The object it is looking for is not yet created in the document.
3. Syntactical error. In my case, closing brace for "if" statement was missing. This caused the runtime error *"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"*.